# jQuery Eventhandler for an dynamically added object

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I got an problem with dynamically added DOM objects in jQuery. First of all I use this:

```
var $input = $('#search-input');
var $usersList = $('#ulist');

       $input.on('input', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/userlist',
            data: {query: $input.val()},
            success: function (response) {

                var json = JSON.parse(response);
                $usersList.empty();
                $.each(json, function (index, val) {
                    $usersList.append("<div id=\"listelem\"><a href=\"#\">" + val + "</a></div>");  

                });
            }
        });
    });



 <div id="ulist"></div>
 <input id="search-input" type="text">
```

to insert divs into usersList. This works well, but now I want to get val from this div when I click on it to process it further. I wrote this piece of code:

```
$usersList.on('click','#listelem', function(){
   alert("clicked");
});
```

When I click on div I got proper alert, but now I have no idea how could I took data from inside of this element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).on('click','#listelem', function(event) {
   alert($(event.target).text());
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7bomzad/5/)

Comment: sorry, but I dont see in your comment things that could help me, I have something like that

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>

when I click on first div I want to take value "1" from it and if I click next one I wish it could pass me "2" value, hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the proper engineering but I have dealt with similar issue while I was developing some requirements. basically as I understood you want to find out the target of the event and drag a value from there? if so you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#listelem', function(event){
var x = event.target.val();// event.target.value; depending on your situation and availability of the method.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tested it but I cant get to target.val() it seems like my event.target cant pass me it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for help. for me proper option was to call

var mem =event.target.innerText;

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with the regular javascript, you don't need Jquery.

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target) {
     console.log("item clicked ", e.target.textContent);
  }
});
```

This should do the job to get the value of current target.